# App is not creating a file and throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, io

The problem is when I send the parameters from the dialog to the mainActivity.

I am sending the parameters by:

```
mainActivity.SaveInfo(info);
```

and it goes to the mainActivity. My code is below:

The RateDialog.java code:

```
public class RateDialog extends DialogFragment {
    public String path;
    public float rate;
    public boolean i;
    PhotosRatingInfo photosRatingInfo;
    PhotosList photosList;

    public RateDialog(String path, float rate, PhotosList photosList) {
        this.path = path;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.photosList = photosList;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater(); 
        View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rate, null);
        final RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

        /** Dialog builder and settings **/ 
            builder.setView(dialog)
                    . 
            setTitle("Rate this photo") 
            . 
            setPositiveButton("Rate",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int id){
                    rate = ratingBar.getRating();
                    Logic.PhotosRatingInfo info = new Logic.PhotosRatingInfo();
                    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                    info.setRate(rate);
                    info.setPhotopath(path);

                    photosList.list.add(info);
                    ***mainActivity.SaveInfo(info);***
                }
            }

            )
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }

                    );
            return builder.create();
        }
}
```

This is the mainactivity (below) and here it gives me  the error `"public java.io.FileOutputStream openFileOutput(java.lang.String name, int mode) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException  " on:

```
FileOutputStream stream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
```

The code of MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void SaveInfo(Logic.PhotosRatingInfo info)
{
   save("PhotosData.txt", info)
}
private void save(String filename, Object data)  {
        try {
            FileOutputStream stream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
            os.writeObject(data);
            //stream.write(filename.getBytes());
            os.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

I am bit new on programing on java so keep in mine (: thx for helping...

Comment: Same as the last time you asked this question.  Please put a breakpoint on `FileOutputStream stream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`  Debug your app.  What value does `filename` have?  Without knowing this, it is not possible to help you.  I also repeat that this, `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity()`, is very bad.  Your app will never work correctly if you do this.

Comment: does PhotosData.txt exists in the same folder as MainActivity?

Comment: for now the MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity() is good for me it is just **test** but in the main activity whan its come to: `FileOutputStream stream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` its not working its return: `public java.io.FileOutputStream openFileOutput(java.lang.String name, int mode) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException { /* compiled code */ }`

Comment: I'll be honest.  It's the best way ;)  Twice I've asked you for the value of `filename`.  Until we know that, we cannot help.  I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: save("PhotosData.txt", info) in the mainactivity

Comment: The point is, that normally, a file without a path saved from an activity will save to private storage.  I have no idea, and I doubt that it is documented or supported, what will happen when you use `new MainActivity()` since it will not have a proper `Context`.  So, put a breakpoint on that line and examine it!  You say it's OK for testing.  I don't agree.  You are not testing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the directories of that file beforehand.

```
File file = new File("./path/to/file.txt");
if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: No you don't.  `openFileOutput` will create the file if it does not exist.  The path must exist but the file need not.